# Loop through and retrieve xml values with Powershell export csv

Tags: xml, powershell, export-to-csv

I've spent a lot of time trying to pull this data - from the following XML - I've "re-purposed a working script that worked well for someone else needs - and is really really close to what I need.

Example XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
    <FANS>
      <FAN type="object">
           <ZONE VALUE="System"/>
           <LABEL VALUE="Fan 1"/>
           <STATUS VALUE="OK"/>
           <SPEED VALUE="26" UNIT="Percentage"/>
      </FAN>
           <FAN type="object">
           <ZONE VALUE = "System"/>
           <LABEL VALUE = "Fan 10"/>
           <STATUS VALUE = "OK"/>
           <SPEED VALUE = "26" UNIT="Percentage"/>
      </FAN>
</FANS>
<TEMPERATURE>
      <TEMP>
           <LABEL VALUE = "01-Inlet Ambient"/>
           <LOCATION VALUE = "Ambient"/>
           <STATUS VALUE = "OK"/>
           <CURRENTREADING VALUE = "20" UNIT="Celsius"/>
           <CAUTION VALUE = "42" UNIT="Celsius"/>
           <CRITICAL VALUE = "46" UNIT="Celsius"/>
      </TEMP>
     </TEMPERATURE>
<POWER_SUPPLIES>
           <SUPPLY>
           <LABEL VALUE = "Power Supply 1"/>
           <PRESENT VALUE = "Yes"/>
           <STATUS VALUE = "Good, In Use"/>
           <PDS VALUE = "No"/>
           <HOTPLUG_CAPABLE VALUE = "Yes"/>
           <MODEL VALUE = "656364-B21                      "/>
           <SPARE VALUE = "Unknown"/>
           <SERIAL_NUMBER VALUE = "5BXRK0DLL7B0S1  "/>
           <CAPACITY VALUE = "1200 Watts"/>
           <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "N/A"/>
      </SUPPLY>
</POWER_SUPPLIES>
</GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
```

There are a lot more than "FAN/TEMP/POWER" etc, hence me attempting to not define this whole "piece" and looking for a loop solution. that will output the values in csv format .  SOOOO, the following scripts when the data is formatted as follows works correctly,however, I don't receive the data in that format, unfortunately.  Also as I move into TEMP, Power, they have different labels/criteria
    SYSTEM
    FAN 1

the code I have so far is as follows (this block is for FAN)  Optimally, I would love to be up one more level, so that it spits out FAN/ZONE/LABEL/... then TEMP/LABEL/LOCATION....   but I can live with doing multiple code blocks for each type, if I can avoid specifying each inner or is it outer member..

```
[xml]$convertMe = Get-Content .\new.xml
[Array]$MeConverted = $convertMe.GetElementsByTagName('FAN')
$Collection = @()
ForEach($Record in $MeConverted){
 $Output = new-object psobject
$Record.selectnodes("*")|%{Add-Member -InputObject $Output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.'#text'}
If($Collection){
    $T2Keys = $Collection|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "VALUE"}|Select-Xml -XPath -Debug
    $T1Keys = $Output|gm |?{$_.MemberType -match "VALUE"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
    $KeysToAdd = $T2Keys|?{$T1Keys -notcontains $_}
    $KeysToAdd|%{$Collection|Add-Member $_ ""}
}
$Collection += $Output
}
$Collection | Export-CSV FAN.csv -notype
```

...repeat for TEMP/POWER/...

I literally spent hours trying to modify the above script to read the value of "VALUE" and studied, get-member, select, etc. but I'm still face-palming at the moment.  And I will likely Face Palm when someone shows me how close I may have been and simple this is!  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had worked on this FOREVER, and must have had a typo the very first time I made an attempt to modify for my needs. and then went down the rabbithole of attempting to figure out how to do this.
I only had to change one thing for my needs.

```
$Record.selectnodes("*")|%{Add-Member -InputObject $Output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.'#text'
```

to

```
$Record.selectnodes("*")|%{Add-Member -InputObject $Output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.'VALUE'
```

I'm wondering if I had possibly typed VALUES last night and not realized it.